# [UIView setTextFont:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I wanted to implement tags in an app I'm developing in swift. So I decided to use [this library](https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView) as it is up to date on swift 3.
In my `super.viewDidLoad` of the class I'm using this `tagView` I've added as per the documentation given on the github page of this third party library:

```
myTagListView.textFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)
myTagListView.alignment = .center
```

And as this view controller is pushed in the stack the app crashes with this message:

> -[UIView setTextFont:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: myTagListView is textview or uiview ,

Comment: From your lib ReadMe: `Drag a view to Storyboard and set Class to TagListView`: My guess is that you didn't did this. `myTagListView` is a `UIView` and not a `TagListView` object.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it's a UIView

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha - check the answer

Comment: @Larme I did added TagListView as custom class for that UIView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ensure that are you added the custom class name as `TagListView` on storyboard or not once

for e.g

[image]

Comment: Yes I've added that! and made it's outlet as `@IBOutlet weak var myTagListView: TagListView!`

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha - check the details iamge once bro

Comment: It turns out that I needed to add `TagListView` in both `Class` and Module` now it's working :D